# Change orientation in UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with a lot of view controllers and navigation controller. I am trying to support both orientations but only portrait works. I know that I have to override this method in all view controllers and return YES and I did like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

but it still doesn't work. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure:

- Your info.plist supports all the
  orientations.
- All the view
  controllers support it as well.
- Your UITabBarController itselfs supports them.